# Pulling out monthly daypart data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm dealing with sales data that looks like this

| Date | Time | Net Amount | Store No | Item Category Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-21 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 08:01:14.627 | 100 | 001 | FOOD |
| 2021-01-31 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 15:42:21.670 | 120 | 002 | FOOD |
| 2021-04-24 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 17:35:30.070 | 160 | 002 | FOOD |
| 2021-03-14 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 13:08:02.073 | 150 | 003 | FOOD |
| 2021-02-27 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 18:33:53.847 | 95 | 001 | FOOD |
| 2021-02-20 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 21:30:24.007 | 180 | 002 | DRINK |
| 2021-04-09 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 07:36:33.930 | 110 | 003 | FOOD |
| 2021-01-29 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 08:02:49.703 | 180 | 002 | FOOD |
| 2021-01-24 00:00:00.000 | 1754-01-01 11:01:00.953 | 110 | 003 | FOOD |

What I need is to pull out monthly data by daypart that would result to this

|  | Jan 2021 | Feb 2021 | Mar 2021 | Apr 2021 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4am to 10:59am | 180 | 0 | 100 | 110 |
| 11am to 1:59pm | 110 | 0 | 150 | 0 |
| 2pm to 3:59am | 120 | 95 | 0 | 160 |

Here's the query I'm currently using:

```
with FoodSales as
(
    select distinct
           concat(year(s.[Date]),'',datename(month,s.[Date])) as TransMonth
           ,sum( s.[Net Amount]*-1) as Sales

    from [dbo].[vw_Sales Entry] as s

    left join [dbo].[vw_Discount Entry] as d
          on s.[Receipt No_]=d.[Receipt No_] 


    where s.[Date] >= '2021-01-01 04:00:00' and s.[Date] <= '2021-04-30 10:59:59'
          and s.[Item Category Code]='FOOD'
          and (d.[Discount Name] is null or d.[Discount Name]='')
         

    group by 
           concat(year(s.[Date]),'',datename(month,s.[Date]))

)

    select * 
    from FoodSales
    pivot( sum(Sales)
    for TransMonth in ([2021January]
                       ,[2021February]
                       ,[2021March]
                       ,[2021April]

      )
      ) as p


;
```

I've also tried using

```
[Date] between '2021-01-01 04:00:00' and '2021-04-30 10:59:59'
```

but when both are tried with another interval, the sales amount just comes out the same.

Comment: Why for january, you are putting time part ? why not sales amount ?

Comment: @VenkataramanR Sorry, forgot to add a blank column header. Thank you for helping me fix this!

Comment: you are welcome. I have added answer. please check.

Comment: what happens when your data ticks over to 2022  and beyond. you probably need dynamic pivot. How is this data consumed? Can you use a reporting tool or feed this into Excel?

Comment: @Harry I only need data from Jan 2021 until June 2021

Comment: Just to note, you shouldn't repost duplicate questions, you should improve your original question and it will get reopened.

Comment: Another note, I would strongly recommend not using `between` its not intuitive how it works. You are better off creating the correct range as you have done, although I would always use `>=' and '<` rather than `>=' and '<=`.

Comment: @DaleK thanks for the tip! yes sorry about reposting, just really needed to get this done already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to you to store time as part of datetime column itself. If you want to keep time separately, store them in the time datatype. I have put sample below considering both date and time being stored in the date column.

You can use DATEPART to demarcate the time ranges and then use pivot to
generate result set as given below:

```sql
declare @TABLE TABLE(dateval datetime, Netamount int, storeno char(3), itemcategorycode char(4))

insert into @table
values
('2021-03-21 04:00:00.000', 100,'001','FOOD'), 
('2021-04-24 10:00:00.000', 160,'002','FOOD')   


select * from
(
SELECT case when datepart(hh,dateval) >= 4 and datepart(hh,dateval) < 11 then '4am to 10:59am' 
            when datepart(hh,dateval) >= 11 and datepart(hh,dateval) < 14 then '11am to 1:59pm' 
            when datepart(hh,dateval) >= 14 and datepart(hh,dateval) < 16 then '2pm to 3:59am' end as timerange,
            
            format(dateval,'MMM yy') AS Month_Year,netamount FROM @table 
            ) as t
            pivot (sum(NetAmount) for month_year in ([Mar 21],[Apr 21])) as pvt
```

| timerange | Mar 21 | Apr 21 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4am to 10:59am | 100 | 160 |